# Connecting data two ways ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm quite new to development and I have recently gotten into ASP.NET Core and I need help to figure out the following:

I need to connect my "characters" to my users upon creation via linking the username to the certain character, how would I go about to do this?

My guess is that upon the create method POST in my "CharactersController" I should be able to edit the "UserName" column for the characters upon creation to be linked to the user currently creating the character. But I am unsure how to do this.

I have tried to find relevant information in the documentation and in different guides but nothing seems to be what I'm looking for.

I appreciate any answers, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already setup authentication / authorization properly, you should be able to use the method

`User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value`

provided by the HttpContextAccessor library.

Comment: Authentication and authorization is set up properly and is working.

But I don't quite understand where that line of code is supposed to go, in the controller probably but how would that connect to the database and save it upon creation? I understand the logic, just not where and how, if that makes sense.

Comment: In your POST method, where you set your model properties for UserName, that's where you'll want to assign it to the User.FindFirst.... code I mentioned. For debug purposes, I typically assign it to a variable first, so I check the value before actually assigning it to the model.